# AuthFlow.CreateCredentialsFromVerifierCode throws error only on load balancer

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, tweetinvi

I am using Tweetinvi for posting images to Twitter.
From our App servers its working fine to post to Twitter.
But, When tried from our load balancer getting this error -

> Error:The credentials are required as the URL does not contain the
> credentials identifier.
>
> Stack Trace: at Tweetinvi.AuthFlow.CreateCredentialsFromVerifierCode(String
> verifierCode, String authorizationId, IAuthenticationContext
> authContext)

My code snippet is like this -

```
var verifierCode = Request.Params.Get("oauth_verifier");
var authorizationId = Request.Params.Get("authorization_id");
var userCreds = AuthFlow.CreateCredentialsFromVerifierCode(verifierCode, authorizationId);
```

I see these parameters(oauth_verifier, authorization_id,..) being passed to the callback page. But still seeing the above error in the call back page.

Note: this issue is only when I try posting to Twitter on our loadbalancer (using the individual servers working fine).
Should I use a different overloaded function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem comes from the fact that you are actually using a load balancer. But let me explain how the authentication works and how you can solve your problem.

```
var appCredentials = new ConsumerCredentials("", "");
var authContext = AuthFlow.InitAuthentication(appCredentials, "");
```

When you call `AuthFlow.InitAuthentication`, it returns an `IAuthenticationContext`. This context contains all the information required to process the callback from Twitter.

But in addition to this, Tweetinvi adds a parameter `authorization_id` to the callback so that it can map the callback request to an actual `IAuthenticationContext`.

```
var authorizationId = Request.Params.Get("authorization_id");
var userCreds = AuthFlow.CreateCredentialsFromVerifierCode(verifierCode, authorizationId);
```

When you call `AuthFlow.CreateCredentialsFromVerifierCode` with an `authorization_id` as a parameter it will look into the local dictionary and try to get the `IAuthenticationContext`.

Because you are using a load balancer, the server executing the `AuthFlow.InitAuthentication` can be different from the server your receiving the callback request.

Because your callback arrives at a different server, it actually result in the `AuthenticationContext` being null.

This is what I tried to explain in the [documentation](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Authentication#note).

#### How to solve this?

What you need to do is to store the `IAuthenticationContext` information required for the `CreateCredentialsFromVerifierCode` to continue its work when it receives the callback. I would suggest you store this in your database.

When you receive your callback you will have to get back these information from your db. To do that I would suggest that when you initally call the `` you add to the callback url a parameter with the value storing the authentication id in your database (e.g. `my_auth_db_id=42`).

```
var authContext = AuthFlow.InitAuthentication(appCredentials, "http://mywebsite.com?my_auth_db_id=42");
```

When your callback arrives you will be able to do :

```
var myDBAuthId = Request.Params.Get("my_auth_db_id");
```

With this value you can now create a new token with the required information (stored in the db).

```
var token = new AuthenticationToken()
{
    AuthorizationKey = "<from_db>",
    AuthorizationSecret = "<from_db>",
    ConsumerCredentials = creds
};
```

Now you are ready to complete the operation:

```
var userCreds = AuthFlow.CreateCredentialsFromVerifierCode(verifierCode, token );
```

I realize this is a big post, but I wanted to explain how it works.
Please let me know if anything does not makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Linvi, But, From the load balancer this is succeeded -  AuthFlow.InitAuthentication(applicationCredentials, callBackURL); 
Upon callback page is loading, AuthFlow.CreateCredentialsFromVerifierCode(verifierCode, authorizationId); is failing.
Are you sure that its some thing to do with settings (time and region correctly set up.) on load balancer?

Comment: As a result of our conversation, a new feature will be implemented added to Tweetinvi 0.9.13.0 that will give use the ability to specify the value of the `authorization_id`. So that you can decide how you want to store the id in your database (int, long, guid...)

Comment: Thanks Linvi for your valuable time. So, if I understand correctly - 
in the first step, after getting the authContext by calling - AuthFlow.InitAuthentication(applicationCredentials, callBackURL), 
I need to store authContext object in our DB (and map to an id)? 
Instead, would it be sufficient if I store only the authContext.Token.AuthorizationKey, authContext.Token.AuthorizationSecret in our DB?

And in the second step (in the callback)- retrieve these values from DB and create the AuthenticationToken object. 
And pass it to AuthFlow.CreateCredentialsFromVerifierCode()

Comment: That is correct. The only thing that you need to store are the `AuthorizationKey` and `AuthorizationSecret`. Though make sure that when you rebuild you `AuthenticationToken` you set the `ConsumerCredentials`.

Comment: Also please note that I have improved the `AuthenticationFlow` yesterday so that such case are easier to implement using [Custom Identifiers](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/issues/243). This will be available in release 0.9.13.0.

Comment: Tweetinvi.dll (0.9.12.2) version has different signature - AuthFlow.CreateCredentialsFromVerifierCode(string verifierCode, IAuthenticationContext context). Struggling how to supply the token created in the previous step. Should I upgrade or downgrade the dll? I got this version when I got it using nuget packageManager

Comment: Can we use this overloaded function - AuthFlow.CreateCredentialsFromVerifierCode(verifierCode, authKeyFromCookie, authSecretFromCookie, key, secret)

Comment: This is a complete  solution for my question. This overloaded function is working fine. May be the documentation needs to be modified. Once again Thank you very much,

Comment: Thé toi en version already exist in 0.9.13.0. Sorry for the confusion.